# How to save only parent table id into child table while saving or updating child table in spring data jpa?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to save/upate  child table data using spring data jpa. while saving data i already have my parent table data so how can i give only my parent data. But while retrieving i want to retrieve all my parent and child objects.

Comment: Its dont automaticly with proper mapping

Comment: If you're still thinking in terms of tables, and not in objects, you shouldn't be using JPA.

Comment: @duffymo I am thinking interms of objects by mapping please help me.

Comment: Nope, your entire question is about tables.  No code, no mapping, no idea what you're doing.

Comment: @Paven is it so hard to google "jpa hiberanate tutorial" or example ?